# No longer have permission to compile via gcc after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cygwin, windows-10

The other day I downloaded cygwin and gcc in order to learn C on my Windows 7 machine.  I made a couple "Hello World!"-style programs, compiled them, etc., everything was fine.  Today I upgraded to Windows 10, and now when I try to compile, I get this error message:

```
$ make [FILENAME]
cc -Wall -g    [FILENAME].c   -o [FILENAME]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot open output file [FILENAME].exe: Permission denied
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: [FILENAME]] Error 1
```

I've searched through a few other threads discussing this error, but have found nothing that solves my problem.  Many suggestions were things I had no idea how even to do!  For example, one person said in a similar thread, "Move to a directory where you are allowed to write."  I don't know how to find a directory where I'm allowed to write, or if that's even my problem.  One suggestion I found that seemed promising was to go to a parent directory and run "chmod a+w [DIRECTORY NAME]".  I did that, and got this error:

```
$ chmod a+w [DIRECTORY NAME]
chmod: changing permissions of '[DIRECTORY NAME]': Permission denied
```

And I can't go any higher in that using "CD ../" so it looks like I've got permission denial all over the shop.

The cygwin directory itself is C:\cygwin-64\, if that matters.

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: I could be wrong but windows 10 replaces the standard command prompt with Powershell or something like that. Have you tried the normal administrator command prompt?

Comment: Run your cygwin as administrator. Probably, on your previous Windows version, you had your UAC disabled.

Comment: Could you post the complete path of compiled files?

Comment: Thanks, V. Kravchenko, running it as an administrator worked.  I used chmod, and now I can compile without needed to run cygwin as an admin every time.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used cygwin in years (and have never used Win10), but I will give it a shot.

What you are asking for help is complicated by multiple issues. One of them is you do not know what permissions are. Another one is Windows 10 may have reset your permissions.

Operating systems have permission models that can restrict what actions a user can do or what files a user can access. On Windows, i'm betting that UAC (that annoying dialog asking for permission) may be blocking chmod from working. (I'm assuming your account is a superuser.) The error before that looks like the folder permission does not allow 'write' access for the compiler to 'open', create a file.

The easiest way to solve this would be to uninstall and reinstall cygwin. The install script should set the proper permissions.

Kudos to you for using gcc on the command line to compile a C program. You may want to consider using Eclipse or NetBeans to help you learn C programming in the future. They have user friendly debuggers that will help you track the state of your program and fix errors.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/neonr

https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html

Comment: Hi JBWyatt4.  Thanks for the response.  Running cygwin as an administrator fixed the problem (I didn't try this at first, since I thought my account was an admin account already!), so I don't think I need to uninstall and reinstall.  Which is fortunate, since installing cygwin and gcc was quite the process!  As for eclipse and netbeans, thanks for the suggestions, but I'd like to try and learn programming without the use of an IDE for now.  If it proves too daunting, I'll give those programs a try.

Comment: probably the upgrade changed the security model or the default user authorization